# Setting Routes in ASP.NET Core web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have this folder structure in my ASP.NET Core application:

[image]

I am trying to set my routes using the following code:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("Default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapGet("/", context =>
        {
            return Task.Run(() => context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index"));
        });
    });
```

My default route is `/Home/Index` but if the user is not authorized then I want to redirect him/her to `/Login` and **not** `/Home/Login`, the current code redirects to `/Home/Login`, which doesn't exist!

What changes should I make in my code?

Comment: Is it razor pages or mvc. You have very strange folders for mvc

Comment: These are razor pages, but I tried to implement `/Home/Index` similar to MVC, setting up HomeController.cs and then making actions.

Comment: Why do you need razor pages ? it makes everything very messy.

Comment: I have no specific reason reason for that but I have been working with razor pages and built my logic around that, don't want to go back and implement it with MVC because the logic is working properly and I am just messing up the routes

Comment: `the current code redirects to /Home/Login`,where you set the redirect route?Or can you tell which page you will redirect to  `/Home/Login`?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is very strange, but it seems to me you can make it using attribute routing

```
[Route("~/Login")]
[Route("~/Home/Login")]
public IActionResult Login()
```